# CombinedAttachments Table subquery is not returning any result in Test class

Tags: unit-test, attachment

In below test class method,   the subquery is not returning any result even after inserting the attachment.

Test CLass :

```
    @isTest
    private class AttachmentRelatedListController_Test {
    static testMethod void projectAttachmentTesting() {

        Milestone1_Project__c proj = Milestone1_Test_Utility.sampleProject('proj');
        insert proj;        
        Attachment a = TestUtil.createAttachment(Proj.Id, True) ;

        note n = new note();
        n.parentId= proj.id; //Id of the opportunity for which you want to add this note
        n.body='inserting note from code'; // body of the note. this should be populated from the notes field that you have shown in the screenshot
        n.title='New Note from code'; // the title of the note
        n.isPrivate=false;  // if private it will be visible only for the owner and any user with modify all permission
        insert n; //insert the record        

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(proj);
        AttachmentRelatedListController controller = new AttachmentRelatedListController(sc);   

       map<Id,Milestone1_Project__c> milestoneProjectMap =  new map<Id,Milestone1_Project__c>([SELECT id, 

                                                                Name, 
                                                                (SELECT Id FROM CombinedAttachments)
                                                         FROM 

    Milestone1_Project__c where id = :proj.id]);

    // To retrieve the results of the map query, you'll want to do the following:

        list<CombinedAttachment> milestoneAttach = new list<CombinedAttachment>();
        set<Id> milestoneProjectId = milestoneProjectMap.keyset();
        list<Milestone1_Project__c>ms1proj = new list<Milestone1_Project__c>();

        for(Id mspId : milestoneProjectId)
        {
           ms1proj.add(milestoneProjectMap.get(mspId));

           milestoneAttach.add(milestoneProjectMap.get(mspId).CombinedAttachments);
        }

        system.debug('milestoneAttach size = ' + milestoneAttach.size()); 
        system.debug('milestoneAttach Id = ' + milestoneAttach[0].Id);
        system.debug('milestoneAttach ParentName = ' + ms1proj[0].Name);                                                         



    }




    }
```

Controller :

```
    public without sharing class AttachmentRelatedListController {

      private final Milestone1_Project__c milestone_project ;
      public list<wrapper> projectRelatedAttachmentList {get; private set;}
      public list<wrapper> projectRelatedMilestonesAttachmentList {get; private set;}
      public list<wrapper> projectRelatedTasksAttachmentList {get; private set;}
      //=========================================================================
      //Constructor
      //=========================================================================//
      public AttachmentRelatedListController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.milestone_project = (Milestone1_Project__c)stdController.getRecord();
        projectRelatedAttachmentList = projectRealtedAttachments(milestone_project.Id);
        projectRelatedMilestonesAttachmentList = projectRealtedMilestonesAttachments(milestone_project.Id);
        projectRelatedTasksAttachmentList = projectRealtedProjectTasksAttachments(milestone_project.Id);
      }
      //=========================================================================
      //Load Project Attachments
      // @return  list<wrapper> 
      //=========================================================================//
      private list<wrapper> projectRealtedAttachments(Id projectId) {      
        list<wrapper> wrpList = new list<wrapper>();  
        list<Milestone1_Project__c> milestoneProjectList =  [SELECT id, 
                                                                    Name, 
                                                                    (SELECT Id ,Title , RecordType ,Parent.Name,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate  FROM CombinedAttachments)
                                                             FROM Milestone1_Project__c where id =:projectId];
        for(Milestone1_Project__c m : milestoneProjectList)
        {   system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>' + m.CombinedAttachments);
             wrpList.addall(populateWrapperList(m.CombinedAttachments , m.Name) );
        }system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>wrpList' + wrpList);
         return sortWrapperList(wrpList);       
      }  
      //=========================================================================
      //Load Project Related Milestones attachments
      // @return  list<wrapper> 
      //=========================================================================//
      private list<wrapper> projectRealtedMilestonesAttachments(Id projectId) {
        list<wrapper> wrpList = new list<wrapper>();    
        list<Milestone1_Milestone__c> milestoneList =  [SELECT id, 
                                                                Name, 
                                                                (SELECT Id ,Title , RecordType ,ParentId,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate  FROM CombinedAttachments order by  CreatedDate desc)
                                                        FROM Milestone1_Milestone__c where Project__c = :projectId order by name ];     
        for(Milestone1_Milestone__c m : milestoneList)
        {   
             wrpList.addall(populateWrapperList(m.CombinedAttachments , m.Name) );
        }   
         //return sortWrapperList(wrpList);  
         return wrpList;
      }

      //=========================================================================
      //Load Project Related Project Tasks attachments
      // @return  list<wrapper> 
      //=========================================================================//
      private list<wrapper> projectRealtedProjectTasksAttachments(Id projectId) {
        list<wrapper> wrpList = new list<wrapper>();    
        list<Milestone1_Task__c> milestoneList =  [SELECT id, 
                                                          Name,
                                                          Project_Milestone__r.Name ,
                                                          (SELECT Id ,Title , RecordType ,ParentId,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate  FROM CombinedAttachments)
                                                   FROM Milestone1_Task__c where Project_Milestone__r.Project__c  = :projectId];
        for(Milestone1_Task__c m : milestoneList)
        {   
             list<Wrapper> temp = populateWrapperList(m.CombinedAttachments , m.Name) ;
             for(Wrapper w : temp){
                w.parentName = m.Project_Milestone__r.Name;
             }

             wrpList.addall(temp);

        }
         return sortWrapperList(wrpList);           
      } 

      //=========================================================================
      // Wrapper Class to Show Data on the VF page collected from Both Attachment
      // Object and ContentDocumentLink
      //=========================================================================//

        public class wrapper{
            public String parentName {get;set;}
            public String AttachmentName {get;set;}
            public String RelatedRecordName {get;set;}
            public String CreatedBy {get;set;}
            public Datetime createdDateF {get;set;}
            public String createdDate {get;set;}
            public String attachmentId {get;set;}
            public wrapper(){
            }
        } 

      //=========================================================================
      // Function to sort the Wrapper class List based on the Creation Date
      // @return  list<wrapper> 
      //=========================================================================//

        private list<wrapper> sortWrapperList(list<wrapper> ListToSort) {
            if(ListToSort == null || ListToSort.size() <= 1) {
                return ListToSort;                  
            }
            list<wrapper> Less = new list<wrapper>();       
            list<wrapper> Greater = new list<wrapper>();    

            integer pivot = 0;              
            wrapper pivotValue = ListToSort[pivot];     
            ListToSort.remove(pivot);               
            for(wrapper x : ListToSort) {           
                if(x.createdDateF > pivotValue.createdDateF ) {
                    Less.add(x);
                } else if(x.createdDateF <= pivotValue.createdDateF ) {
                    Greater.add(x);
                }   
            }       
            list<wrapper> returnList = new list<wrapper> ();        
            returnList.addAll(sortWrapperList(Less));
            returnList.add(pivotValue); 
            returnList.addAll(sortWrapperList(Greater));    
            return returnList; 
        }  

      //=========================================================================
      //Function to populate the wrapper List
      // @return  list<Wrapper> 
      //=========================================================================//
      private list<Wrapper> populateWrapperList(list<CombinedAttachment> lstCombinedAttachments ,String name){
        list<wrapper> wrpList = new list<wrapper>(); 
             For(CombinedAttachment cA :lstCombinedAttachments ){
                wrapper wrp = new wrapper();
                wrp.createdDateF = cA.CreatedDate;
                wrp.createdDate =cA.CreatedDate.format();
                wrp.AttachmentName = cA.Title;
                wrp.CreatedBy = cA.CreatedBy.Name;
                wrp.RelatedRecordName = name;
                wrp.attachmentId = cA.id;
                wrpList.add(wrp);       
             }      
        return wrpList;
      }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it's not returning any results? I don't see any debug statements in your code that would tell you that's the case.

Comment: @crmprogdev , I used assert statements to ensure that the sub-query is not returning anything . Also i have modified the code while posting here to make it more general .

Comment: what api version is the testmethod running at?

Comment: I am using 32 . @crop1645

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want your `system.debug` statement to look something more like:

```
system.debug('milestoneProjectList size = ' + milestoneProjectList.size());
```

Equally important, if you're concerned about the attachment, you'd also need something like:

```
list<Attacment>milestoneAttach = new list<Attachment>(); 
milestoneAttach = milestoneProjectList.CombinedAttachments; 
system.debug('milestoneAttach size = ' + milestoneAttach.size());
```

which would cover the subquery.

I don't see where your current system debug statement covers whether or not your query returned any results.

As an alternative, you could also have done something like the following:

```
boolean result1 = milestoneProjectList.isEmpty();
system.debug('result1 = ' + result1);
```

If result1 is true, then it was empty and the query didn't return any results, if false, then the query returned results. However, if that were the case, I'd also be doing a system assert on the insert of `proj` because regardless of whether the attachment inserted, the query should return results!

The same type of thing could also have been done for the subquery and similarly a system debug to confirm the attachment was inserted or alternatively use a `database insert` for both objects, then get the id's afterward so you'll already have them to use when you do your assertions or for comparison in your debug statements.

For more on what I've just described, see the Apex Code under [database class - insert](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_insert_3) and related methods.

**Edit:** Response to revised question/comments regarding query.

One of the things I notice about your query is that the subquery includes fields that are not specified when the attachment is defined, specifically `Title` and `RecordType`. I don't know if those are required fields or not or if they're provided by your controller, but I wouldn't be querying for information that may not exist. I would recommend restructuring your query to return a map as follows:

```
map<Id,Milestone1_Project__c>milestoneProjectMap = new map([SELECT id, 
                        Name, 
                        (SELECT Id , Title, RecordType, Parent.Name, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate  FROM CombinedAttachments)
                        FROM Milestone1_Project__c where id = :proj.id]);

// To retrieve the results of the map query, you'll want to do the following:

list<CombinedAttachment>milestoneAttach = new list<CombinedAttachment>();
set<Id>milestoneProjectId = milestoneProjectMap.keyset();
list<Milestone1_Project__c>ms1proj = new list<<Milestone1_Project__c>();

for(Id mspId : milestoneProjectId)
{
   ms1proj = milestoneProjectMap.get(milestoneProjectId);

   milestoneAttach = ms1proj.CombinedAttachments;
}

system.debug('milestoneAttach size = ' + milestoneAttach.size()); 
system.debug('milestoneAttach Id = ' + milestoneAttach.Id);
system.debug('milestoneAttach ParentName = ' + ms1proj[0].Name);
```

The above will allow you to easily modify it to do more than one project and attachment record insertion for bulk testing; something your previous method didn't support. Unless you plan to do a system assert or system.debug on all of the fields you're querying. I would remove anything from your query that you don't actually need and just get the Id of the attachment if you're not going to assert it's value since it appears that all you really want to know is whether or not the attachment was saved. If you want to know more, then by all means, query it, but be certain to make use of the information.

If this doesn't solve your issue, then please post your code for your `AttachmentRelatedListController`.

Comment: Sir my code is not getting covered of the class i have created this test class for . I know how to put asserts and check for size and everything else . I have put the query here in test class just to show what is there in my class . The list<Milestone1_Project__c> milestoneProjectList has been put in the test class just for the stackexchange to show where i am not getting any results . Off-course milestoneProjectList is not empty , but the subquery result is all empty . To correct the query you suggested , I have updated the code . Please have a look how it should be.

Comment: See my edited response above. Please recognize in the future that we can only respond to posts here based on the code you include with it. No one here knows what level of coder you are until you gain reputation that demonstrates your abilities.

Comment: No sir . its Still not helping .  Please see the Full controller as well as test class code i have attached . Sorry for the bad edits i was not able to figure out how to put that in proper code block . I am new to Stackexchange .

Comment: In actual i wanted to check the size of list<wrapper> projectRelatedAttachmentList in the test class which should be greater than 0 if the subquery returns the results .

Comment: If the size of `milestoneAttach > 0`, which is what the subquery returned , then your `list<wrapper> projectRelatedAttachmentList` will be greater than 0. They are the same except the latter has been passed into the wrapper along with the name of the project. The difference is that putting the query results into a map makes it easier to get the results of the subquery.

Comment: @crmdev any reason why the size of  size of milestoneAttach  is equal to  0 ???

Comment: If `milestoneAttach` is equal to 0, then the attachments did not get inserted by your class. Again, I'd be checking to see if you need to specify the `RecordType` or anything else in order to have a successful insert since that was something you were querying for initially.